# How to merge all functions into a single function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to merge all three functions into a search function. If the user searches with name, it should call that name field rows only, and remaining things like search by author and price functions should be disabled. I am writing all three functions separately and three different API routes for that. Now I want one API route if the user searches by name or author or price and all three functions in a single function.

**FileController.php**

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function searchBooksByAuthor($author)
    {
        $books = Books::all();
        if (User::find($books->user_id = auth()->id())->books) {
            $searchBooks = Books::where("author", "like", "%".$author."%")->get();
        }
    }

    public function searchbooks($name)
    {
        $books = Books::all();
        if (User::find($books->user_id = auth()->id())->books) {
            return Books::where("name", "like", "%".$name."%")->get();
        }
    }

    public function searchBooksbyPrice($price)
    {
        $books = Books::all();
        if (User::find($books->user_id = auth()->id())->books) {
            return Books::where("price", $price)->get();
        }
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ['auth.jwt']], function () {
    Route::get('searchBooksbyName/{name}', [FileController::class, 'searchbooks']);
    Route::get('searchBookbyAuthor/{author}', 
        [FileController::class, 'searchBooksByAuthor']);
    Route::get('searchBookbyprice/{price}', 
        [FileController::class, 'searchBooksbyPrice']);
});
```

Comment: it's quite simple..make a search route with query string. and then search by them..what is confusing you here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::middleware('auth.jwt')->prefix('searchBooksby')->group(function (){
  Route::get('{name}',[FileController::class,'searchbooks']);
  Route::get('{author}',[FileController::class,'searchBooksByAuthor']);
  Route::get('{price}',[FileController::class,'searchBooksbyPrice']);
});
```

The above is what you are looking for. However there is more generic way to solve this problem without using function for each case. Look at the below. Just call one api and pass two parameter. First is **filterBy** that is the name of the column. In our case **name** , **author** or **price** and the second parameter is the value to filter for.

```
Route::middleware('auth.jwt')->prefix('searchBooksby')->group(function (){
    Route::get('{searchBy}/{searchByValue}'[FileController::class,'searchbooks']);
});
```

Now there will be only one function that will handle all this logic.

```
public function searchBooks(Request $request , $searchBy, $searchByValue){
    /*
     * Prepare your query without searchBy Parameter

     */
    $db = DB::table('books');

    /*
     * searchBy parameter should be the same as the name of column (more generic)
     * e.g
     * search by book name then column name in database table should be name
     * search by value should be the corrosponding value of that column
     */

    $whereClause = [];
    $whereClause [$searchBy] = $searchByValue;
    /*
     * [name => 'abc']
     * [author => 'xyz']
     * ['price' => 1234]
     */

    /*
     * Now you can filter in more generic way without using conditions and seperate functions
     */

    $results = $db->where($whereClause)->get();
    return response()->json($results);
}
```